# Identify LCD module connector type

Tags: connector, lcd

I recently got a mini LCD module from Mouser (Newhaven Display Model #NHD-C160100DiZ-FSW-FBW, datasheet [here](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/291/NHD-C160100DiZ-FSW-FBW-53905.pdf). It came with a 14-pin ribbon-like connector that I've never seen before. Can anyone help me to identify the type of connector, so that I can purchase the female equivalent? See photo below:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As illustrated in the data sheet, that is a 14-conductor 0.5 mm pitch flat flex cable

Four of the 14 connections are the same signal, and two are unused, which accounts for the distortion of the visual pattern.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that's what that part of the data sheet meant. Much appreciated!